# Grid DataWindow Issues in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

1. I have a Data Window to display data from DB, and the following code in DW `clicked` event to display latest data from DB.

   ```
   if row > 0 then
       ReselectRow(row)
   end if
   ```

   I changed Data window style to Grid style. Now if i click on a row in DW it Is showing error `ora-00936 missing expression` error.

   Can any body faced this problem earlier kindly help me how to solve this issue?
2. While sorting data in Grid Data Window after sorting its selecting whole column with 'Black' color.

   I want to change this black color to any other decent color. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

That error "ora-00936 missing expression" is from oracle, check your sql code.

And, no, there is not way to change that. But you can do this:

uncheck mouse selection (this property makes the selected column go black), then in the event click search for the field of the clicked header, finally use "Modify" function to change the color of that field (you can select any color you want!).

Remember to reset all the fields to their original colors.